# preg_slit not working like it should? - php

Tags: php

preg_slit function is not working correctly for me. Function outputs 1 value in the array instead of 3. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/DQscO)

```
$response = '--batch_QXn9PvafngA_AAdxhnxliYc
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-3368-post

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "3057934386064000"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 09:06:33 GMT
Expires: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 09:06:33 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 860


--batch_QXn9PvafngA_AAdxhnxliYc
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-3369-post

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "3057934386064000"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 09:06:33 GMT
Expires: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 09:06:33 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 860

}

--batch_QXn9PvafngA_AAdxhnxliYc--';


echo '<pre>';
print_r( preg_split("/(\--batch_*:)+/", $response) );
```

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of results you are looking for exactly, but there are some problems here:

- `*` is a quantifier so `_*:` means 0 or more `_` characters followed by a `:`. You don't have this in your text anywhere, so it will never match anything.
- If you want to match over multiple lines to get to a `:`, you need the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

So your modified expression would look something like this, using non-greedy matching for the characters before the `:`:

```
/(--batch_.*?:)+/s
```

This you would probably need to adapt further to get what you want.

Comment: Well i got the pattern from somewhere. Glad you helped me. It works with your pattern.